# Warning 1264 Out of range value adjusted for column (datetime column)

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the thing, I have two fields to capture when a user will be available for something: a Y(1)/N(0) available now field and an available date (only populated if the user is not immediately available).  It was decided (before I came on) that if the user is available now, the value would be set to 1 and that date would remain blank (date is not a required field).

I have php code to set the date to be blank when the user updates from No(0) to Yes(1).  When the user clicks Yes from No, the date isn't blanked initially (and I think it's due to this warning - which I found when I set the date on the db myself).  When I click Yes a second time, it actually blanks the date time column as I intended.

Is there a way to get this to work the first time around?

(If I could have my way, I would just set the date to the current day, but that doesn't seem to be my call.)

Thanks,
Waddler

Comment: How are you "blanking" the date column?

Comment: Fails the first time, works the second? Echo the sql each time and compare.

Comment: questions about code, without posting the code, are just dumb.

Comment: Joe: I'm blanking it by sending 0000-00-00 00:00:00.  I got that value b/c I saw it used in a test for the information that I am working with.

webbiedave: when I run the code myself against the db, I get an warning message, but it does it anyway.  I don't have to run it twice.  I'm new to PHP/MySQL, so I don't know what differences there are between me running the sql query and the code running the sql query.

Dagon: I didn't post the code because I did not think it was relevant.  The code works.  This seemed like more of a conceptual question to me.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use NULL when no date is desired. Here is what you need to do:

**1)** In your database schema, set the available date column to have a default of NULL. Make sure the field is not set to "NOT NULL".

**2)** We need to make sure in handling this field, we set it to NULL which is not the same thing as 'NULL' by the way. So, when inserting records (if using PDO), for example, do something like this:

```
// Not sure where you get this, so change it as necessary
$userAvailable = 1;

try {
   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost', 'myusername', 'mypass');
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
   // Handle errors...
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable(isAvail,dateAvail) VALUES(:isAvail, :dateAvail)');

// Bind first parameter as integer
$stmt->bindValue(':isAvail', $userAvailable, PDO::PARAM_INT)

// Bind null value. Use PDO::PARAM_INT because there is often
// issues with using PDO::PARAM_NULL
$stmt->bindValue(':dateAvail', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Now that we have prepared our query and made sure it is good against
// SQL injection attacks, lets run it
$stmt->execute();
```

**3)** When reading the value from the database, you can now use PHP's [is_null()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function rather than trying to figure out if a date such as '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is valid or not.

```
// Get data from database
...

if( is_null($row['dateAvail']) )
{
   echo("User is available now!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it datetime instead of timestamp.